# How "yum" & "dnf" package managers update executing software?

Tags: linux, software-updates

In Windows Operating system a software need to be closed before updating. Like we need to restart Google Chrome to update it. How package managers in Linux systems (specifically `yum` & `dnf` in Fedora like Linux) update any software when it's open. Although updated version effects only after restarting the software, but I want to know how package managers update while a software is executing? Some files must be removed and replaced during update. How this is done while the files are executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File locking in Windows and Linux (and other UNIX-like systems) work somewhat differently. Windows usually prevents modification on executable binary files which are currently mapped to a process. This is why you can not update software while a program is running, because the lock prevents modification/replacement of these binaries.

On Linux, locking usually is not used, or is co-operative (not enforced). Mandatory locking exists on Linux, but it [isn't reliable](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man2/fcntl.2.html). If a binary executable file mapped to a running process is modified or deleted (during a software update) the filesystem won't reclaim the disk space mapped until the last handle is released. This way the already running process can still access the pages mapped to old files.